# WCF - How to automatically pass Windows Credentials of the current logged in user

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to use a NetTcpBinding with Windows Credential without the WCF client having to pass or a username and password combination to a remote WCF Service. Basically, I want the Windows Credentials of the user the WCF Client is ran under to be passed to the remote WCF Service automatically. My remote WCF Service is hosted using a Windows Service and **not** using IIs.

Here's my binding:

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding()
{
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
    Security = new NetTcpSecurity()
    {
        Mode = SecurityMode.Transport,
        Transport = new TcpTransportSecurity()
        {
            ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows
        }
    }

};
```

I read that I could do the following:

```
    ChannelFactory<T> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, "net.tcp://addressToTheService");
    channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

However, doing this results in the following error:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.Security.Authentication.InvalidCredentialException: The server has rejected the client credentials. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed
    at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartReceiveBlob(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextSend(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartReceiveBlob(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] message, LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, ChannelBinding binding, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeProvider.WindowsStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty& remoteSecurity)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUpgrade(Stream stream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection& connection, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
```

However, if I replace the line by this one, it works!:

```
channelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")
```

I'm just trying to avoid putting the username, password and domain. What I want, is that if the user is allowed to access the server the WCF Service is installed on, then it should have access to the service.